# How to switch/rotate every two lines with sed/awk?

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have been doing this by hand and I just can't do it anymore-- I have thousands of lines and I think this is a job for sed or awk.

Essentially, we have a file like this:

```
A sentence X
A matching sentence Y
A sentence Z
A matching sentence N
```

This pattern continues for the entire file. I want to flip every sentence and matching sentence so the entire file will end up like:

```
A matching sentence Y
A sentence X
A matching sentence N
A sentence Z
```

Any tips?

edit: extending the initial problem

Dimitre Radoulov provided a great answer for the initial problem. This is an extension of the main problem-- some more details:

Let's say we have an organized file (due to the sed line Dimitre gave, the file is organized). However, now I want to organize the file alphabetically but only using the language (English) of the second line.

```
watashi 
me
annyonghaseyo
hello
dobroye utro!
Good morning!
```

I would like to organize alphabetically via the English sentences (every 2nd sentence). Given the above input, this should be the output:

```
dobroye utro!
Good morning!
annyonghaseyo
hello
watashi
me
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sed 'N; 
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\
\1/' infile
```

`N` - append the next line of input into the pattern space
`\(.*\)\n\(.*\)` - save the matching parts of the pattern space
the one before and the one after the newline.
`\2\\
\1` - exchange the two lines (\1 is the first saved part,
\2 the second). Use escaped literal newline for portability

With some sed implementations you could use the escape sequence
\n: `\2\n\1` instead.

Comment: Thanks-- this worked like gold! Would it be possible to re-arrange alphabetically based on the first letter of the first line? Also, it seems like the file size jumped up about 30% after this, possibly inserted some symbols? I don't see any white space etc. I remove all trailing white space with ":%s/\s\+$//" in vim. edit: I saved the output via > output.txt if that matters.

Comment: @Google, could you post a bigger sample of your input and an example of the desired output (given the last ordering requirement)?

Comment: I updated the initial problem-- I hope it's clear. If not let me know.

Answer (score 21):

For the first part of the question, here is a one way to swap every other line with each other in sed without using regular expressions:

```
sed -n 'h;n;p;g;p'
```

The `-n` command line suppresses the automatic printing. Command `h` puts copies the current line from the pattern space to the hold space, `n` reads in the next line to the pattern space and `p` prints it; `g` copies the first line from the hold space back to the pattern space, bringing the first line back into the pattern space, and `p` prints it.

Comment: If the input has an odd number of lines, the final line will not be output.  If output of that line is desired: `sed -n '$p;h;n;p;g;p'`

Comment: If you change the `g` to a `G` you only need the last `p`.

Comment: how do I apply this to the 2 first lines only?

Comment: @vitor, to swap only the first two lines: `sed -n '1{h;n;p;g};p'`

Answer (score 7):

First question:

```
awk '{x = $0; getline; print; print x}' filename
```

next question: sort by 2nd line

```
paste - - < filename | sort -f -t $'\t' -k 2 | tr '\t' '\n'
```

which outputs:

```
dobroye utro!
Good morning!
annyonghaseyo
hello
watashi
me
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an input file like this:

```
A sentence X
Z matching sentence Y
A sentence Z
B matching sentence N
A sentence Z
M matching sentence N
```

You could do both exchange and sort with *Perl*:

```
perl -lne'
 $_{ $_ } = $v unless $. % 2;
 $v = $_;
 END {
  print $_, $/, $_{ $_ }
    for sort keys %_; 
   }' infile
```

The output I get is:

```
% perl -lne'
 $_{ $_ } = $v unless $. % 2;
 $v = $_;
 END {
  print $_, $/, $_{ $_ }
    for sort keys %_;
   }' infile
B matching sentence N
A sentence Z
M matching sentence N
A sentence Z
Z matching sentence Y
A sentence X
```

If you want to order by the first line (before the exchange):

```
perl -lne'
 $_{ $_ } = $v unless $. % 2;
 $v = $_;
 END {
  print $_, $/, $_{ $_ }
    for sort {
      $_{ $a } cmp $_{ $b }
      } keys %_; 
   }' infile
```

So, if the original file looks like this:

```
% cat infile1
me
watashi 
hello
annyonghaseyo
Good morning!
dobroye utro!
```

The output should look like this:

```
% perl -lne'
 $_{ $_ } = $v unless $. % 2;
 $v = $_;
 END {
  print $_, $/, $_{ $_ }
    for sort {
  $_{ $a } cmp $_{ $b }
  } keys %_;
   }' infile1
dobroye utro!
Good morning!
annyonghaseyo
hello
watashi 
me
```

This version should handle duplicate records correctly:

```
perl -lne'
 $_{ $_, $. } = $v unless $. % 2;
 $v = $_;
 END {
    print substr( $_, 0, length() - 1) , $/, $_{ $_ }
    for sort {
      $_{ $a } cmp $_{ $b }
      } keys %_; 
   }' infile
```

And another version, inspired by the solution posted by Glenn (record exchange included and assuming the pattern _ZZ_ is not present in the text file):

```
sed 'N; 
  s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1_ZZ_\2/' infile | 
    sort |
      sed 's/\(.*\)_ZZ_\(.*\)/\2\
\1/'
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works perfect-- I wrapped it up in a bash script. You saved me a lot of work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After careful inspection it seems it does its job well but doesn't handle duplicates. Is there any way to handle gracefully? It seems like it drops any duplicates.