# Reverse the line order of line pairs

Tags: regex, sorting, text, awk, grep

I need to reverse the order of text line pairs ex:

- firstline1
- secondline1
- firstline2
- secondline2
- firstline3
- secondline3

to

- secondline1
- firstline1
- secondline2
- firstline2
- secondline3
- firstline3

I'm searching a way to automate it (i've got 650 lines to sort), any magic solutions?
Thanks

Comment: See [how-to-switch-rotate-every-two-lines-with-sed-awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818284/how-to-switch-rotate-every-two-lines-with-sed-awk).

Comment: If you have this in a file, just: cat file.txt | sed -n 'h;n;p;g;p' Don't forget to give credit to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6820157/1007273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Assumptions

Both solutions below require that lines actually be in pairs. Otherwise, the last line won't get printed.

#### SED Solution

```
sed -n 'h; s/.*//; n; G; p' /tmp/foo
```

1. Disable automatic printing.
2. Copy line to hold space.
3. Delete pattern space.
4. Read next line into pattern space.
5. Append hold space.
6. Print pattern space.

#### AWK Solution

```
awk -F'\n' 'NR%2==1 {line=$0}; NR%2==0 {print $1 "\n" line}' /tmp/foo
```

1. Don't split lines into fields on whitespace.
2. If line is odd, store the line.
3. If line is even, print the current line plus the stored line.

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm, added it as a bbedit text filter:

Comment: created a .sh file containing #!/bin/sh cat "$1"| sed -n 'h; s/.*//; n; G; p' placed it in library/Application support/BBEdit/Text Filter/Myscript.sh the script is now directly accessible in "Apply text filter" menu et voilà!

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete pattern space since `n` overwrites it.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Hmmm. I was getting extra line spaces before without the substitution, but I can't reproduce the behavior. The substitution does no harm, but `sed -n 'h; n; G; p' /tmp/foo` works just fine, too. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

More obvious shell version:

```
while read -r firstline ; read -r secondline
do
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "$secondline" "$firstline"
done
```