# Interchange every other line with awk

Tags: bash, awk

If I have the input:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

How can I use `awk` to print

```
line2
line1
line4
line3
line6
line5
```

I feel like `awk` is likely the best tool since I would like to do this from a stream, but would bash or anything else be a better way?

Comment: This is the same as [How to switch/rotate every two lines with sed/awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6818284/1983854), only that that one was then extended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
awk 'NR%2{prev=$0; next} {print ; print prev}'
```

**Test**

```
$ awk 'NR%2{prev=$0; next} {print ; print prev}' input
line2
line1
line4
line3
line6
line5
```

Comment: Because i don't like `next` an alternative `awk '!(NR%2){print;print x}{x=$0}'`

Comment: @JID if you are golfing, it could be shorter with sed.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `sed` for this:

```
sed -n 'h;n;p;g;p'
```

How it works: with `h` we store the current line in the "hold space", move on to the next line with `n`, print it with `p`, retrieve the saved line with `g` and then print it in turn (`p` again).

Comment: Can use `G` in place of `p;g`

Answer (score 2):

even though OP has accepted an answer, I would add this sed one-liner:

```
sed -n '1~2{h;n};p;g;p' file
```

small test with `seq`

```
kent$ seq 6|sed -n '1~2{h;n};p;g;p'
2
1
4
3
6
5
```

Comment: can be a bit simpler: `sed -n 'h;n;G;p'`

Comment: @glennjackman you are absolutely right, think it twice, `1~2` doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`. But be careful with `getline`: if not used correctly, it may bite.

```
awk '{f=$0;getline;print $0 RS f}' file
line2
line1
line4
line3
line6
line5
```

Comment: wrt stating `if not used correctly, it may bite.` why not instead simply show it used correctly (http://awk.info/?tip/getline)? I think the answer is probably because then the resulting code is longer and more complicated and still more error prone than simply not using getline (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28239790/1745001) so then posting it becomes completely pointless.